# Ajax dynamic data with column bar chart

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

Is it possible to run the highcharts column bar charts?  I've tried it a couple of times and unfortunately this no real way to refresh the data without reloading it.

I whipped up some pseudo code which is the way I did it at work (I'm not there now so can't get to the code).

Should I whip up a loop and run it like 5,000 times or something with a 5 second delay?  I'm not real sure how to proceed.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
< your typical ajax call function here
    return some value;
>


$(function () {
    <var ajax_far = ajax_function();>
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Some Bar'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 100,
                y: 70,
                floating: true,
                shadow: true
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
                series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [ajax_var]

            }]
        });
    });

}, 5000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

put your ajax code in one function that it call from ready function...try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
example();
 setInterval("example()",5000);
}
function example()
{
//ajax code here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ajax call should simply obtain new data for the chart to display. There is no need to redraw the entire chart, you can just replace the series data, or add indivual points. Here is a good article on doing this on the highcharts website here http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-live-data, but the ajax code they suggest is:

```
/**
 * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again.
 */
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'live-server-data.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // Shift if the series is longer than 2.

            // Add the point.
            chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

            // Call it again after one second.
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

In this code, the requestData function is called every second (via setTimout). It obtains a new data point via an ajax call to live-server-data.php and uses chart.series[0].addPoint to add it to the chart.

If the ajax call returned the entire series, you would call chart.series[0].setData to replace the entiire series.

The only thing you need to worry about is making sure the chart is created before you start call addPoint or setData.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(function () {
    var chart;
    var list;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
               //all chart attr here
                 }
                //other attr
           }
 chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "service",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) 
    { 
           chart.series[0].setData(data);
        }
    }),1000); //will set ur data to ajax data every 1 sec
                  if u want to update to existing chart data try addPoint()
});
});
```